# DEBUG = True Django

Tags: django

In a production environment, why do I hear people saying that leaving DEBUG = True is potentially dangerous?

What is one example where someone might exploit this security issue to perform a malicious task on my server?

Comment: you should accept the right ans .

Comment: You should accept @PraveenGollakota's answer

Answer (score 28):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug

"Never deploy a site into production with DEBUG turned on.

Did you catch that? NEVER deploy a site into production with DEBUG turned on.

One of the main features of debug mode is the display of detailed error pages. If your app raises an exception when DEBUG is True, Django will display a detailed traceback, including a lot of metadata about your environment, such as all the currently defined Django settings (from settings.py)."

Basically, it's a gaping security hole.

It also wastes a lot of memory:

"It is also important to remember that when running with DEBUG turned on, Django will remember every SQL query it executes. This is useful when you're debugging, but it'll rapidly consume memory on a production server."

Comment: So what we need to assign **DEBUG** in production ?

Comment: This didn't seem to answer the question. The OP seems to know not to enable DEBUG in production; he asked for **one example** where someone might exploit the security issue to perform a malicious task on the server. Reiterating to "never do it" is a lot like in that Family Guy episode where Quagmire says he wasn't going to hook up with a call girl and Joe says "Good. Don't.", and then Quagmire is like "I already know not to do that, you don't have to tell me not to", to which Joe responds: "Good, don't".

Comment: Adding this note b/c I down-voted the answers.   The "did you catch that, NEVER" is really not called-for.  There is nothing wrong with someone asking experts to explain the reasoning behind "common wisdom".

Answer (score 21):

Django tries its best to obfuscate secure information in your debug page, but it's not perfect.

By default any settings which include KEY (starting Django 1.4), SECRET etc. are automatically replaced with ***. However if someone decides to get creative and call SECRET as SECURE_STR or whatever, that will be displayed as plain text! Would you want that? Also it's just more fodder for someone to hack into your server easily.

Answer (score 0):

If the DEBUG = True
Django raised detailed error page, it contains every url details as well as our important credentials also, it is helpful for developers to understanding and solve bugs. In the production time must keep DEBUG = False to avoid the detailed error page.